# Parshat Lech Lecha - Hagar having a separate malach

Tags: rashi, malach-angel, parashat-lech-lecha, hagar

Does anyone know a pshat in what is the depth behind Hagar having a separate malach for every single dibbur like Rashi brings, why couldn't there just be one malach for the whole story?

Answer (score 4):

The Maskil Lidavid (there) explains because 1 malach can't do 2 jobs. He there explains what job each malach is doing, each malach had his own unique message to tell Hagar.